# Is there a way to disable the ads in Yahoo Mail? Is there a plug-in or something?

Tags: yahoo-mail

I understand that the ads keep Yahoo! mail free. But, when they play on the right side of the browser window or change, the actions disrupt my typing when I am entering a long message on my computer. Sometimes I have to stop and wait for the ad to change in order to keep typing.

I am using public library computers that use IE. I know FireFox has plug-ins. The ads may use shockwave or something like that. (That is a guess.)

Does IE have something like plug-ins where I can disable something in the IE Internet options to stop the ads? It is either that or I will have to compose longer messages in MS Word first, and then cut/paste them to Yahoo! mail.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AdBlock Plus.  Once you get it installed click on the preferences and select all of the items in the list.  Typically the top one isn't checked.  Check that one as well.  The list should include

> Adblock Warning Removal List
>   EasyList
>   Malware Domains
>   EasyPrivacy

What's also great about this is when you watch YouTube videos, it also removes all those ads as well along with countless other ads.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Dale. Unfortunately, the public computers I am using don't allow me to install this. But, I see that I can get a portable version of FireFox, put it on my flash drive and try the same thing you suggested with AdBlock.

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks. I don't mind using portable FF if it means I can write long messages without interruptions. (I certainly can't say anything bad about our local libraries. I understand why they need strict security like that. They are fantastic with what they provide.)